# Changing the value of a hidden field in a reactive form in Angular

Tags: forms, angular

I have a reactive form that has the same (two) input text fields for several different scenarios. When a user selects a scenario option from a list, the form is shown and a hidden field within that form is updated with a keyword for the selected scenario, e.g.

```
<input formControlName="action" type="hidden" value="{{theaction}}">
```

My problem is that while that field is being updated (i.e. I can see it in reveal codes), the value doesn't seem to be bound to the form when it's submitted (i.e. the field is empty on arrival at the server).

What bit about reactive forms am I missing here?

Thanks/Tom

Comment: 1. I'd favour sending form data via Angular's `http` service. 2. You can always set the form control value in code-behind.

Comment: value -> ngModel: `[ngModel]="theaction"`. This will cause the form to receive the newest value of "theaction" to be submitted.

Comment: can you post how do you update the hidden field?

Comment: Thanks Z.B - ngModel was the key for me. Cheers/Tom

Comment: @Pengyy: when the scenario option is selected, this function is called ...
  toggleForm(which){
    if (which==='new'){
      this.theaction = "new";
    }
    if (which==='edit'){
      this.theaction = "edit";
    }

Comment: @user118504 it's not recommend to use `ngModel` along with reactiveform, you should use `patchValue` or `setValue` of FormControl.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. Am now using: this.person.patchValue({
          theaction: 'edit'
        }); (where 'person' is the formGroup)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a need to include information on a reactive form (e.g. an id), some property of my data model that should not be exposed on the UI. I created a `FormControl` for the property, which allowed me to store and manipulate the value, but I did not create a corresponding `<input>` in the template. Worked like a charm. E.g.

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [null],                              //hidden field
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['']
});
```

in the template

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">

  First Name: <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />

  Last Name:  <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />

  [...]

</form>
```